# difference between using 'BETWEEN AND' and '[a-b]%' to compare the letter in the SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, wildcard

I am practicing some SQL questions on W3resource and met one question 
'Write a SQL statement to find those salesmen with all other information and name started with other than any latter within 'A' and 'L'.'
The original answer is

```
    SELECT * FROM salesman WHERE name NOT BETWEEN 'A' and 'L';
```

I tried the wildcard expression '[A-L]%' but it doesn't work.

```
    SELECT * FROM salesman WHERE name LIKE '[^A-L]%'
```

The link of this questions is : 
https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-wildcard-special-operator-exercise-8.php

Can someone provide some explanation regarding to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the target DBMS? That `LIKE` pattern doesn't work in all DBMS, in fact AFAIK it's a speciality of SQL Server only. The original answer in contrast, is pretty much "standard" SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not equivalent.

Any word that starts with `L` matches the `NOT BETWEEN` -- "Lowly", "Likable", "Lithuanian".

The `LIKE` does not match any word that starts with "L" at all.

The equivalent comparison would be more like:

```
where name  < 'A' and name >= 'M'
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Yes, that is a `NOT BETWEEN` in the question.

Comment: Make sense, thanks for the explanation @GordonLinoff